# Как задать id элементу равное id другого элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery, случайные-числа

Не могу понять, как сделать ассоциацию между элементами.
Задача такая: есть несколько групп элементов с классами Start и End, нужно чтобы id Start равнялось id End, но чтобы этот id отличался от других групп таких элементов, например:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="start" id="one">
  </div>
  <div class="end" id="one">
  </div>
  <div class="start" id="two">
  </div>
  <div class="end" id="two">
  </div>
  <div class="start" id="three">
  </div>
  <div class="end" id="three">
  </div>
</div>
```

Все элементы лежат в одном контейнере. Для получения разных значений id Start, использую рандомные числа по этой функции

```js
var ID = function () {
  return Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
};
```

Comment: Вопрос не совсем понятен, но нельзя ли присваивать элементам `id="start_one", id="end_one"` и т.д?

Comment: `id` должен быть уникален. На странице не может быть более одного элемента с одним и тем же `id`

Comment: Нужно получить случайное значение (это делает рандомайзер), записать его в id Start, а потом передать в id End. С первым шагом я справился, а вот второй не могу понять, как реализовать. При попытке присвоить id End id Start, у меня присваивается значение только из первого Start

Comment: @smellyshovel ну тогда можно передавать значение id Start в атрибут data End, но у меня передается для всех End значения только из первого Start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let start = document.querySelectorAll('.start'),
    end = document.querySelectorAll('.end');

if ( start.length == end.length ) {
  for (let i = start.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    start[i].id = end[i].id;
  }
}
```